# ld linking problem on Mac M1 arm64 architecture, using GNU11 compilers gcc, gfortran

Tags: gcc, ld, apple-m1, arm64, openmpi

I'm building a set of libraries on Mac M1 (arm64 architecture), Big Sur and use GNU11 compilers (gcc, gfortran, g++), as well as openmpi 4.1.2 for multi-processing. All is done as a command-line using a Terminal.app, which is running as Apple native, and NOT using Rosetta Translation. The steps taken: 1) GCC, g++, gfortran are installed using "brew install gcc@11", then symbolic links created in /opt/homebrew/bin/  for gcc -> gcc-11, g++ -> g++-11 ; 2) openmpi 4.1.2 installed, with mpicc based on gcc,  mpixx based on g++, and mpifort/mpif90 based on gfortran; 3) command-line tools installed as "xcode-select --install".
Getting the problem with finally linking of the libraries:

````
...
/Users/Natalie/openmpi/bin/mpifort -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib  -fallow-argument-mismatch -fallow-invalid-boz  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=11.6 CMakeFiles/cmTC_9a888.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o -o cmTC_9a888
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_sgemm_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in testFortranCompiler.f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTC_9a888] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_9a888/fast] Error 2 ```
````

Comment: having the same problem